# LIKE not working with NVARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM hr_companies
WHERE NameLang2 LIKE '111კომპანია'
```

but it returns no rows. I see that `hr_companies` table has a column named `NameLang2` of `varchar` type. I also used `ltrim rtrim` but still nothing is returned.

Please suggest how to fix problem I am facing now.

Comment: what are these characters you're using! they should be causing your issue

Comment: You say `nvarchar` in your title, but `varchar` in your body ... which is it now?? If you're using `NVARCHAR`, your string literals should be prefixed with a `N'....'` : `WHERE NameLang2 LIKE N'111კომპანია'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
declare @tabe table(id int ,data  nvarchar(max))

insert into @tabe 
values (1,N'नाम'),(2,N'गणेश')

select * from @tabe where data like N'%गणे%'
```

Output:

```
id    data

2     गणेश
```

Comment: This answer would be much better if it explained the significance of the differences.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add `%%` to your search:

```
SELECT * FROM hr_companies
WHERE NameLang2 LIKE '%111კომპანია%'
```

Comment: even wildcard doesnt work with non english text

Comment: it works like this though SELECT * FROM hr_companies
WHERE NameLang2 LIKE '%111%'

Answer (score 2):

Use wildcard

```
SELECT * FROM hr_companies
WHERE NameLang2 LIKE '111კომპანია%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM hr_companies
WHERE NameLang2 LIKE N'%111კომპანია%'
```